# Angular keyvalue pipe and looping trough 2 objects

Tags: angular, typescript, key-value

I am trying to refactor some code I have inherited but not quite sure to understand how.
In my ts file I am declaring the object of the keys I want to include:

```
keysInclude = {
property1: 'Property 1',
property2: 'Property 2',
property3: 'Property 3',
}

myObject = {
property1: 'some string',
property2: 'some string',
property3: 'some string',
property4: 'some property I don't want to show'
property5: 'some property I don't want to show'
}

then in my template I have this part of the code

<div *ngFor = " let keyValuePair of keysInclude | keyvalue; let i=index">
<span>{{keyValuePair.value}}</span>
<span>{{myObject[keyValuePair.key]}}</span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

I am struggling to type my keysInclude, Ideally I would like add the types without refactoring much but I am afraid that I don't really understand how to do it. myObject type will always be defined and will always have same properties as my keys inside keysInclude object . I have tried to use Record and also KeyValue interface of Angular but I always have errors that my Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type {} cant be used to index myObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyof` (to infer your type keys) in combination with `Partial` (to ba able to specify a subgroup of the keys to be shown) to achieve what you want like this:

```js
keysInclude: { [Key in keyof Partial<MyObjectType>]: string } = {
  property1: 'Property 1',
  property2: 'Property 2',
  property3: 'Property 3',
};
```

Comment: but my object always have defined type

Comment: and I get error that myObject only refers to type but is being used as a value. PS: myObject is an interface.

Comment: yes check the second part of my answer, if you have an interface for your myObject, you can do keysInclude: Record<keyof MyObjectInterface, string>

Comment: I see but this obligates me to add all the keys of myObject to keysInclude and I only want to have those keys that I want to display in the template.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check again

Comment: this si great I also got the same idea but again I can't index like this myObject[keysInclude.key]. I got the same error that type string cant be used to index myObject

Comment: that's because of valuekey pipe which returns the key as string, you can work around this by using a method and casting the type, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dp5ev7?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts